# closing bootstrap modal... sometimes it doesn't close

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm opening a bootstrap modal window to show a 'processing information message' with `m_arc_dl.php`.  After `p_archive_dl.php` has run (the processing finishes) I am closing the modal window.

What I have noticed is every now and then the modal does not close... it seems to happen when the response from `p_archive_dl.php` is really quick.  I am guessing maybe this is because the modal fades in and it hasn't fully loaded before the close call happens?

Any suggestions so I can prevent this?

```
// show processing message
$('#modal-ajax').load(
  '/modals/m_arc_dl.php',
  function() {
    $(this).modal('show');          
  }
);

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/process/p_archive_dl.php',
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function (response) {

    if (response.success)
    {                       
        // create hidden iframe with the 'src' attribute set to the file to download
        var dlif = $('<iframe/>',{'src':'/showdownload.php?file='+response.file+'&files='+response.files+'&ts=1&un=1'}).hide();

        // append iframe to body
        $(document.body).append(dlif);  
    }

    // close the modal
    $('#modal-ajax').modal('hide');                                              
});
```

Comment: You have two asynchronous requests, so it's not surprising that sometimes their success callbacks are executed in not-you-want order. You can either make second request on first one success or use some kind of flag to determine whether `$(this).modal('show');` should be executed or not.

Comment: In my case problem was with incomplete html tags. Like forgetting to close a tag poperly. Then after closing a modal I was stuck with black transparent background.

Comment: @Regent - didn't even cross my mind, but that makes sense. Just wrapped the second ajax in a function and calling it from the first after modal is opened.  Seems to do the trick.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @user756659 you're welcome. As it is a bad in SO when question has no answer (or answer in comments), either you can delete the question or I can post this as an answer.

Comment: Post an answer... I will make sure to select it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two asynchronous requests, so it's not surprising that sometimes their success callbacks are executed in not-you-want order.

You can either make second request on first one success or use flag to determine whether `$(this).modal('show');` should be executed or not.

Example of first approach:

```
// show processing message
$('#modal-ajax').load(
    '/modals/m_arc_dl.php',
    function() {
        $(this).modal('show');
        makeRequest();
    }
);

function makeRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/process/p_archive_dl.php',
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (response.success) {                       
            // create hidden iframe with the 'src' attribute set to the file to download
            var dlif = $('<iframe/>', {'src': '/showdownload.php?file=' + response.file + '&files=' + response.files + '&ts=1&un=1'}).hide();
            // append iframe to body
            $(document.body).append(dlif);  
        }
        // close the modal
        $('#modal-ajax').modal('hide');                                              
    });
}
```